# Ideas for making a backyard fort moveable

Tags: foundation, play-structures

I'm in the planning stage of a backyard fort similar to [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Backyard-Fort/), standing on six 4x4 posts with the floor roughly three feet above grade with far more structure than the linked example.  Since this thing will need to be placed within a utility easement, one requirement will be that it can be moved.  I'm thinking of placing skids made of 4x4s under the posts, joining them to the posts with mortises/tenons, then fixing the skids to concrete pilings. Then I can unscrew the fasteners from the pilings and pull the fort out of the easement on demand on the skids. But will a truck pull this beast?  And will the fort be too top-heavy to be moved safely without tipping?  Should I skip the pilings and simply level the ground? Are there any other options for fort mobility that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 3):

Make the base frame with locating points so you can fit axles underneath. Also make sure the frame will be limited in its flexing.

There are truck companies with special low trailers that may help, but will you like the price?

I would think around and design around the issue.

Comment: Regarding flexing, yes, my version of the linked example will have floor joists of 2x10 and 2x6 cross bracing on the posts beneath the floor.

Comment: Gotta say, I like the axles idea. I see a flurry of new questions while _that_ is being designed!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd count on that being particularly mobile. There's going to be a *lot* of weight on that and dragging it across the ground, even if you put a bevel on the end of the skids, is going to be iffy.

There's some diagonal bracing hidden behind the paneling at the deck level, but I'm not certain I'd count on that to hold the whole thing square when you're towing it around and it's <s>bouncing</s> <s>lumbering</s> wobbling across the yard. Even if your lawn is putting-green smooth, it's going to be a rough ride. (And any kid worth his salt is going to want to ride it!)

If you use the type of anchors to hold it to the concrete blocks that were mentioned in those instructions, you'll have a hard time getting the wood to slide square out of it, and an even harder time getting it to slide back in. Realistically, you'd probably have to jack it in and out to get it to settle properly into each anchor. If it happens to be in the middle of a hot, humid streak in the summer, the wood will have swollen quite a bit and that will make it really rough.

Will a truck pull it? #ItDepends. Are you talking a '78 Datsun pickup, or a Peterbilt? What kind of surface will you be driving on when you're moving it? Will it have just rained? What kind of towing capacity does the truck have? What kind of tires and condition? That's really an unanswerable question for us without a *lot* more detail, and even then, who knows...

Honestly, I'd seriously consider relocating it, or if you can't, modifying the design to keep it out of the easement area so you don't ever have to think about moving it.

As a side note, painting the floor will leave a fairly slick floor surface. It will be *extra* slick if the kids are playing on it in the rain. Also, I wouldn't go with OSB for an exterior project, I don't think it will hold up to the elements particularly well - I'd go with plywood, even if it's a few bucks more.

If you build it and make it mobile, I'd love to have you come back to post a video of it being detached from its moorings, moved, reset and reattached.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was expecting, but not what I was hoping.

Comment: +1 for any kid will wan to ride it... :)

Comment: Glad to hear you were being "realistically optimistic" @FingLixon. I saw your comment on uprating the floor joists and adding cross bracing. That will improve stiffness, but also increase weight - a double-edge sword...

Answer (score 1):

What about a "two skid" approach, where you lay a set of skids down, then lay a slippery layer - something like the "bunk slicks" they use on boat trailers, then lay another set of skids down, and build the fort on top of those. Pin/bolt or plate those top and bottom skid pairs together.

Then, when/if moving time comes, unpin, and the fort/top skids should slide off the bottom skids, perhaps onto a set of log rollers.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. This answer is intriguing and sounds like it might have potential. Can you please [edit] to elaborate on what a "bunk slick" is? Then take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you'll know what to expect around here.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty.. open trenching is largely a thing of the past. There's liability (people falling in, as well as cave-ins), and a lot of cost associated with restoring landscape after an open dig. In the unlikely event that a utility does come along wanting to install new lines through that easement, it's probable that they'd be using directional boring and would tunnel under whatever you have there whether bare dirt, grass, or a play house.

If ease of relocation is important because the yard might be re-arranged, or because you might want to bring the play house along in a move, that's one thing. But I wouldn't go to any great pains to design and build a play house specifically for ease of relocation just because it's over an easement. Build it to satisfy any authority having jurisdiction that it's not a permanent structure, ie that it *could* be moved if necessary.. but expect a move will never actually happen.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the "utility easement" is for a large power line tower and heavy equipment may need to be brought in for modification/repair work. It's possible that there are already utilities buried there, and they may need to get to them for repair/maintenance work and _that_ might require digging....

Comment: There's a sewer line down part of this easement already (although not the portion in question here). It was trenched in 2006. You're not wrong, but... You might not be right either. 

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the (nearly) final product: like the starting model, treated 4x4 posts hold up the roof.  But the bottom ends of those posts are joined via pinned mortise/tenon joints to 4x6 runners that can potentially be jacked up to be placed on rollers. Floor framing is treated 2x8 and cross bracing is treated 2x6.

[image: Nearly complete fort]

I was taken by the "bunk slicks" idea and ordered nylon strips.  The idea was to lay 4x4s along the ground, screw the nylon strips to them, then put the 4x6 runners atop them then start building upward (with some 2x8s strapped to both sides of the runners and slicks to hold them together).  But the design changed after that, the nylon became too short for the new design, the end of summer was approaching, and I needed to get to work.  So I abandoned the bunk slicks and instead have gone with the primary strategy of simply hoping for the easement to remain unused.  I'm hoping to find another use for that nylon so that ~US$200 doesn't go completely to waste.